# How can I set up callbacks in my UI after user has submitted tx via Metamask?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have a webapp that calls a smart contract via web3js/Metamask and I want to reload certain elements once the user has submitted the tx.

How can I set up the callbacks for those reload actions?

Answer (score 1):

All metamask calls suppose to have callback function where you can do whatever you want. Below is the sample snippet for your reference.

```
myContractInstance.method(parameter,{ from:result[0],
                            to:recipient,
                            value:  0, 
                        }, function(err, transactionHash) {
                            if (!err)
                            {
                                $('#btnSample').css('display','none');
                                $('#info').html("Transaction succeeded. Track <a href='https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/"+transactionHash +"'>"+here+"</a>");
                                console.log(transactionHash); 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                console.log('Error in the method');
                                console.log(error);
                            };
                        });
```

You can even have ajax call within `if(!err)` to save or record any other action.